# jira python api issue vs search_issues give different results

Tags: python, jira

All, I am attempting to retrieve a Jira issue using the python jira api. I have the issue key.

If I do this:

```
myissue = jira.issue(issuekey)      # eg 'NS-12'
print ("Description {0}".format(myissue.fields.description))
```

I get an exception:

```
AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'description'
```

If I do this:

```
for myissue in jira.search_issues('issuekey={0}'.format(issuekey)):
    print ("Description {0}".format(myissue.fields.description))
```

I get the correct description returned. I have tried using

```
myissue = jira.issue(issuekey, fields="description")
myissue = jira.issue(issuekey, expand="description")
```

with no success.

Can anyone explain why the two methods return different results, or a better approach than having to do a search to get the issue when I already know the key.

Thanks,